# Tomcat port in use in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I tried searching for this problem here and in other forums but could not resolve this issue.
I have downloaded NetBeansBeans 7.0 Java EE pack which also installs Tomcat 7 which it did.
I created sample web application and when trying to deploy I get an error:
**Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use.**

I tried changing the ports but no success. However, when i try to run same Tomcat  from Command prompt using "startup.bat" command, it runs successfully.
Operating system is Vista. I tried checking for open ports using "netstat -a" but no open port for 8080. also tried to see if any "java.exe" process is running  but it was not.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Vista, especially after hibernation, doesn't free a previously used port. Have you tried restarting the pc?

Comment: hi.yes. restarted the PC.(also uninstalled and installed NetBeans 7 again)

Comment: For changing the port (and other information) have you followed the instructions in this link? http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansedTomcat

Comment: I think that is for building Tomcat project and running              in NetBeans? I don't see information related to port in use error.

Comment: i have disabled McAfee Antivirus and Windows firewall too.